# PHP - Change every url in html depending on domain

Tags: php, html

Using PHP I would like to be able to change every url in a specific HTML page depending on domain.

This code allows me to change urls one by one but I'm sure there is a better way:

```
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

switch ($domain) {

     case "example2.com":
         $url1 = "http://".$domain."/secondsubfolder/thispage.html";
         break;

     case "example3.com":
         $url1 = "http://".$domain."/thirdsubfolder/thispage.html";
         break;

     default:
         $url1 = "http://example.com/firstsubfolder/thispage.html";

}
```

HTML:

```
<a href=" <?php echo $url1 ?> ">first url</a>
```

**Notice that I also need to change the first subfolder depending on domain, thats why I can't use relative urls.**

So my aim is to be able change every url in my default HTML code:

```
<a href="example.com/firstsubfolder/thispage.html">hello</a>
<a href="example.com/firstsubfolder/somefolder/otherpage.html">bye</a>
```

should change if my website is accessed through example2.com

```
<a href="example2.com/secondsubfolder/thispage.html" >hello</a> 
<a href="example2.com/secondsubfolder/somefolder/otherpage.html">bye</a>
```

Comment: you have multiple domains, pointing to one file system? so is `thispage.html` identical on each domain?

Comment: @Dagon actually I have Magento with different store views. Each of them accesible trough different domains. Magento automatically changes system urls based on the domain (just as I'm pretending). thispage.html almost the same, only urls and styles change.

Comment: being Magento  specific i suggest asking on: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You don't have to write a switch, you can use an associative array (with entries `'example2.com' => 'secondsubfolder'` and so on) and write `echo 'http://' . $thearray[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]  .'/thispage.html';` but you will have to handle each URL like that separately, yes.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear to me but I guess you need something like:

```
<?php
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$scriptPath = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

switch ($domain) {

     case "example2.com":
         $domain = "example2.com";
         $folder = "secondsubfolder";
         break;

     case "example3.com":
         $domain = "example3.com";
         $folder = "thirdsubfolder";
         break;

     default:
        $domain = "example.com";
        $folder = "thirdsubfolder";

}

$scriptPath = preg_replace('%^/.*?/%', "/$folder/", $scriptPath);
echo "http://{$domain}{$scriptPath}";
```